# Use pivot_longer to seperate columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
id = c("1", "2", "3")
IN1999 = c(1, 1, 0)
IN2000 = c(1, 0, 1)
TEST1999 = c(10, 12, NA)
TEST2000 = c(15, NA, 11)

df <- data.frame(id, IN1999, IN2000, TEST1999, TEST2000)
```

I am trying to use pivot_longer to change it into this form:

```
  id year IN TEST
1  1 1999  1   10
2  1 2000  1   15
3  2 1999  1   12
4  2 2000  0   NA
5  3 1999  0   NA
6  3 2000  1   11
```

My current code looks like this

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(col = !id, names_to = c(".value", "year"), 
               names_sep = 4)
```

but obviousely by setting `names_sep = 4`, r cuts `IN1999` and `IN2000` at the wrong place. How can I set the argument so that r can separate the column name from the last four digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `names_sep`-argument in `pivot_longer` also accepts regex expressions, that will allow you to split before the occurrence of four digits as in this example below:

```r
library(tidyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(col = !id, names_to = c(".value", "year"), 
               names_sep = "(?=\\d{4})")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id    year     IN  TEST
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1     1999      1    10
2 1     2000      1    15
3 2     1999      1    12
4 2     2000      0    NA
5 3     1999      0    NA
6 3     2000      1    11
```